# How to decrypt password of UserInterface entity in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, authorization

I have a web application which uses the `UserInterface` of Symfony for login and registering users.

And I have developed another application in Java which will have to communicate with my web application only if the user of the Java app is registered with the web application.

So in my Java application I'll ask a login and a password and I will send that to the web application.

But how can I check if it's the good user because I can't see the clear password of an user with `UserInterface` of Symfony?

I know it's for security reason, however in my special case I think that I have to decrypt my password user.

Comment: why not try to login to your api, if you can you will have an 200 else you will have an 401 and not to decrypt the password

Comment: In spite of the name (PasswordEncoder), Symfony actually hashes their passwords making it effectively impossible to retrieve the original clear text.  I suppose you could plug in your own encoder which would allow decrypting.  Huge security violation as you noted.  In any event, as @GrenierJ has suggested, there does not seem to be any reason you can't simply check the username/password using the normal Symfony security flow.

Comment: There's a way that Symfony can check the password during login, no? You can use that programmatically through an API for example. Alternatively, the password is likely hashed in a manner that can be replicated in Java too, so you can do a password validation in Java as well if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

First and foremost, because passwords and not *encrypted*. They go through a one-way [cryptographic hashing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

You can either verify the password against the hash in Symfony's side (by calling an endpoint and providing the credentials, and letting Symfony tell if they are OK or not)

Or, if your Java application has access to the same DB, replicate the verification on this side. (Something [like this](https://dzone.com/articles/hashing-passwords-in-java-with-bcrypt) if you are using Bcrypt on Symfony; or something [like this](https://github.com/kosprov/jargon2-api) if you are using Argon2i).